# Should I use state computation? Spark Streaming state computation explanation

Tags: java, apache-spark, state, spark-streaming

Here is my case: I receive data from different devices, which have their own signature, a timestamp and a flag. I then filter the `(flag==SAVE_VALUE)` in a file using a `foreachRDD` function, but only if it passes this condition:

```
(it is the first time I receive this signature)
OR
(I already have this signature && the timestamp is older than an hour)
```

This, until I was in a local environment, meant for me to use a Map, where I stored all the IDs and the last timestamp received. Right now I would like to move this logic in a Spark like one. How should I do it?
I feel this is a case for a stateful Dstream, but I cannot completely understand:

- How should I store a map-like rdd in a Dstream? Or how do I create a single "*map RDD*"
- How do I compare the new data arriving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `mapWithState()`, it is exactly what you want.

In the `StateSpecFunction`, you can determine if you want to update, keep, or remove the current state, whenever a new value arrives for the same key. You have access to both the current state and the new one, so you can do any type of comparison between the two.

It has also built-in support for timeouts, and can be partitioned to multiple executors.

You can access the global map by calling `stateSnapshots()` on the return value of `mapWithState()`. Otherwise the return value will be determined by the return values of your `StateSpecFunction`, per batch.

`mapWithState()` was added in Spark 1.6, before that there was a similar function called `updateStateByKey()`, which did mostly the same, but performed worse on larger datasets.

Comment: @DanielZolnai Thank you. I had already read about mapWithState() before posting my question, but did not catch *how* it could have helped me. I can understand the concept, or at least see the reasoning behind it, but I can't manage to find a way to implement it.

Comment: This example is pretty good in my opinion: https://docs.cloud.databricks.com/docs/spark/1.6/examples/Streaming%20mapWithState.html